# tmux: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, tmux

Recently upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10 and when I tried to run tmux it throwing this error.

```
tmux: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How Can I solve this?

**apt-cache policy tmux** results this

```
  Installed: 2.5-3build1
  Candidate: 2.5-3build1
  Version table:
 *** 2.5-3build1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: The version of `tmux` in 17.10 requires a different version of libevent than yours does. What's the output of `apt-cache policy tmux`?

Comment: @ fkraiem question updated

Comment: That is the correct version... How about `which tmux` and `ldd $(which tmux)`?

Comment: @fkraiem which tmux ----> /usr/local/bin/tmux

Comment: The official tmux is at `/usr/bin/tmux`. Where is this `/usr/local/bin/tmux` coming from? Installed from source?

Comment: @fkraiem ldd $(which tmux) ---> `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe7709000)
 libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fa1fd055000)
 libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fa1fce2c000)
 libevent-2.0.so.5 => not found
 libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fa1fcc12000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa1fc832000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa1fd259000)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue and came to find I had two `tmux` binaries installed.
My suggestion for simplicity:

```
apt remove tmux
which tmux
```

If you have a response the 2nd time, `rm` it then reinstall

Comment: I love you!!  I love you!!

Answer (score 0):

This could help on ubuntu as symbolic links might be need to be created to all the `/usr/local/libevent/` paths using `ln -s` after compilation from source:

https://noknow.info/it/os/install_libevent_from_source

```
wget https://github.com/libevent/libevent/releases/download/release-2.1.11-stable/libevent-2.1.11-stable.tar.gz
tar xvfz libevent-2.1.11-stable.tar.gz
cd libevent-2.1.11-stable
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libevent/2_1_11
make
make install
```